# Vim -- "E117: Unknown Function: MySys"

Tags: vim

When I attempt to set OS specific settings in my .vimrc,

eg:

```
if MySys() == "Windows"  
    set guifont=Lucida\ Console:h10
endif
```

I get the error code `"E117: Unknown Function: MySys"`
This happens on both Linux and Windows. On Windows I'm using 7.3, and in Linux I'm using whatever Ubuntu has in their repository (7.2, I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of `MySys()`, but `has("win32")` works for me for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. That works. There's a 1000 or so hits for "mysys() vimrc" on Google, so I assume this function existed in earlier versions of Vim.

Comment: It looks from those hits like `mysys()` is just a commonly defined user function.

Comment: Here is [an example](http://amix.dk/blog/post/162) of how at least one person defines this function, for anyone else's future reference.

Answer (score 1):

MySys looks to be the creation of Amir Salihefendic. His site, amix.dk has a ton of great vim information beyond the simple "move around with hjkl" stuff. It's a great resource.

The post where he defines the MySys() function is [here](http://amix.dk/blog/post/162):

```
fun! MySys()
  return "windows"
endfun

set runtimepath=~/vim_local,$VIMRUNTIME
source ~/vim_local/vimrc
```